# how to create a stacked DNC in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

There are 3 implementations of DNC using tensorflow that i saw :
[DeepMind](https://github.com/deepmind/dnc) , [Mostafa-Samir](https://github.com/Mostafa-Samir/DNC-tensorflow) and [Siraj Raval](https://github.com/llSourcell/differentiable_neural_computer_LIVE).

Basically what i want to understand is how to create a layer of DNC that can be used anywhere (Keras-like layer). For instance: create 2 layer of DNC. Can i do it with tensorflow (or using one of those 3 implementations)? and any tutorial/guideline to do it? Thanks!